# Models are'nt loaded yet error when trying to get object of a model by it's ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

i have two models like this :

```
class Author(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
      code  = models.IntegerField(unique = True)

class Book(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
      author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And i want to list some Book with specific author and use them in another model like below:

```
class SomeBook(models.Model):
      books = Book.objects.all().values('title').filter(author__code=20)

      text = models.TextField(default=books)
```

But i receive the "Models aren't loaded yet" Error.

i also tried to use the serializers to get the object in josn format But still the same error appears.

I also look at the similar question in here but nothings helped

How i can fix this error.

Comment: did you try put upcoming lines at the beginning of the file? 
import django
django.setup()

Comment: Models **don't** work that way. Don't know what you are trying to do, but models are simply an abstraction of the database tables. What you try to do makes no sense.

Comment: I tried it but receive another error:"populate() isn't reentrant"@SırrıKırımlıoğlu

Comment: For every other fields in model this work except the ForeignKey field. @AbdulAzizBarkat